# Creating a WPF UI based on testing for best fit of content

Tags: c#, wpf

I am pretty new to WPF, and I have been having trouble trying to determine how to go about creating the screens I require.

I have an application that I am attempting to re-develop on WPF. When the program begins a text file is loaded into a memory object which holds survey question/answer definitions. For questions with preset answer choices, such as radiobutton (single) or checkbox (multiple) entry, the goal is to show all of the answers on the screen at once (with no scrolling) whenever possible. To do this, the answers are tested between 4 different display formats, ranging from 1 to 4 columns of answers, for the best fit. Once the best fit has been found, the elements are drawn to the screen in whatever format was determined.

This works perfectly in WinForms, but it seems to be a problem in WPF based on the way it handles UI creation and measurements. Any help/ideas that can be offered would be greatly appreciated...

MORE INFO:

[image: Design]

A - Single column layout

B - Two Column

C - Three Column

D - Four Column

E - Tow Column Example where the text wrapped for the Checkbox or RadioButton example.

** The key here is that when the page loads, I do not yet know which of these formats will fit my content without scrolling, let alone best fit. That's where I'm getting hung up right now. In the old WinForms version of my application I measure all my content prior to display it, so I know what format will hold it best.

Another wrinkle being that I always want the columns when 2+ to be about equal in height. So if it just barely doesn't fit in a single column, I'd want to see two shorter columns, instead of 1 long column and a very short one beside it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't include any code because it was really more of a design question than a code question. Our original application was a WinForms application, WPF is the way we'd like to move. I will post a few drawings/screenshots with a deeper explanation of what I'm looking to do.

Comment: An ItemsControl with a custom panel will be your best bet. Check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should rather use the relative sizing layout opportunities that WPF provides so you don't need to worry about testing the specific layout like in WinForms.

You can, for example:

- Set your Window to automatically size to your content.
- Set up
  relative sizes of columns (i.e. 1/3 vs 2/3) in a grid layout so that
  any content will always display in those ratios.
- Set up maximum and
  minimum sizes of columns/grids/windows so that content will wrap, if
  necessary.

Think less in terms of what fixed layout strategy works and more in terms of how you can make the layout react to the content, much like a web-based CSS-based system.

**Edit:**

Based on the update with the V1-4 layouts, you should consider whether you can determine the layout based on the content supplied. If so, create appropriate generic `DataTemplates` for the content `ViewModel` type (your `ViewModel` could be a single class - this is one of the strengths of WPF's databinding and MVVM) and use a `TemplateSelector` to serve up the `DataTemplate` (layout) for the content based on some selection logic.

**Edit (no 2):**

To measure text use `FormattedText` class.

To measure an entire `Control` call `Measure()` with a specific `Size`. If the `DesiredSize` is larger than the `Measure()` `Size` argument then the content overflows the bounds provided and may scroll depending on whether you allow scrolling (you can disable scrolling using the `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` attached property but the content will be clipped instead)

Comment: Appreciate the comment. I added some more info to my original post.  Unfortunately, I am dealing with a client who is insistent that content DOES NOT scroll unless it is absolutely necessary. They are adamant that I use their V1-V4,VA system of screen layout. V1-V4 are explicitly a certain number of columns, while VA tests for fit without scrolling. If none of the 1-4 columns fit within the space given without scrolling, then I am to take the option that produced the shortest total space, and make it scroll.

Comment: Understood. Have a look at my edit. You can measure everything manually by invoking Measure() and checking DesiredSize and ViewportSize, but I would urge you to consider whether there are characteristics of the data (i.e. length of text, number of questions) that can drive your layout instead.

Comment: Interesting. In terms of determining the layout based on content supplied, is there any means of measuring strings or controls (perhaps even off screen? I have basic logic that can use this to predict the fit. It would however require me being able to calculate some degree of measurements prior to the screen being drawn. EDIT: just saw your comment here. I will dig into that. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, 1 last thing. Is there any limitation on when I can measure() and actually get values back?

Comment: Measuring text - check out `FormattedText` class.

`Measure()` must be called on the UI thread - it doesn't return values so much as populate the particular Control's `DesiredSize` property.

Answer (score 0):

- Make your Columns fixed width.
- Put your columns in a WrapPanel

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the existing WrapPanel for laying out multiple elements. Then if this does not fit your needs I would go and implement a custom panel deriving from the [PanelClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel(v=vs.110).aspx) 
Check an implementation of a custom panel [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF)